# @Transactional not working with Spring Boot and JDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My service should save data to a parent and child database tables, and rollback when an error ocurrs. I've tried forcing an error, using a hardcoded `RuntimeException`, and found the transaction gets commited no matter what.
What I'm I missing?
I'm using Spring Boot 2, including the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` dependency.

Database is Oracle 11g.

Main configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service layer:

```
    @Service
    public class MyBean {

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;        
    private final MyDAO myDao;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean (NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, MyDAO myDao) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.myDao= myDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveData(...){
        myDao.saveData(jdbcTemplate, ...);
    }

}
```

DAO:

```
public void saveData(jdbcTemplate, ...){
    saveDataInParentDatatable(jdbcTemplate, ...);
    saveDataInChildDatatable(jdbcTemplate, ...);
}
private void saveDataInChildDatatable(jdbcTemplate, ...){
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: The database is Oracle 11g

Comment: How is `saveData` being called.

Comment: Just added more code showing the call

Comment: I hope your are not using `@Transactional` on  `saveDataInParentDatatable `

Comment: How are you calling the service layer saveData method and is there any transactional annotation on your dao class?

Comment: The @Transactional is only in the MyBean.saveData method, nowhere else.

Comment: You have produced quite a contraption. Why are you passing around the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`? That fact should be hidden in your dao, also what is your `saveDataInParentDatatable` doing and how is the `saveData` method being called.

Comment: saveDataInParentDatatable just makes an insert with the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Comment: The NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is there as an argument just for better testing design

Comment: @pablo have you resolved this?

Comment: I didn't. I was wasting too much time so changed everything to another way of doing things (which worked).

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue. I'm assuming that you were calling the MyBean.saveData method at MyBean's another method.

After searching, trying and failing a lot, I found this link: http://ignaciosuay.com/why-is-spring-ignoring-transactional/

In it, it's explained that when the invoked method is in the same class where is it invoked, the @Transactional annotation is ignored. The [Spring explanation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) for it is:

> “In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
>   the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your
>   initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct.”

So I created another class to encapsulate my DAO method calling, used its method instead and it worked.

So for this case, it could be something like:

MyBean:

```
@Service
public class MyBean {

    MyBean2 bean2;

    public void saveData(...){
        bean2.saveData(jdbcTemplate, ...);
    }
}
```

MyBean2:

```
@Service
public class MyBean2 {

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;        
    private final MyDAO myDao;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean2 (NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, MyDAO myDao) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.myDao= myDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveData(...){
        myDao.saveData(jdbcTemplate, ...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Comment: please move method with Transactional annotation in separate class then try.. Move below method in xyz.java

Comment: Let me know if it will work for you.. Usually Transactional does not work if it is in same class

Answer (score 1):

recommended use:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
```